# Is pulling up a method into a generic base class a breaking change

Tags: c#, api-design

I have a library currently structured as this:

```cs
class Base<T> 
{
}

class Derived : Base<int>
{
    public int Foo();
}

class AnotherDerived : Base<string>
{
}
```

I would like to add a similar `Foo()` to `AnotherDerived` and as the implementation would be identical for both, I would like to pull up `Foo()` into their shared parent class `Base` like below.

```cs
class Base<T> 
{
    public T Foo();
}

class Derived : Base<int>
{
}

class AnotherDerived : Base<string>
{
}
```

Doing this changes the return type for `Foo()` from `int` to `T`.
Changing the return type of a member is [listed](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/breaking-change-rules.md#signatures) as a breaking change.
But since `Derived` is generic in `Base<T>` with `T=int` the code can still compile, at least for this example.

```cs
int foo = myDerived.Foo();
```

I don't want to introduce breaking changes to my users, so my question is whether this kind of pull up in any way be considered a breaking change?
Moving into the base itself should not be a [breaking change](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/breaking-change-rules.md#members)

> Moving a method onto a class higher in the hierarchy tree of the type from which it was removed

An alternative implementation that enables code sharing and should not be a breaking change, but which I would like to avoid if the pull up is non-breaking, could be:

```cs
class Base<T> 
{
    protected T Foo();
}

class Derived : Base<int>
{
    public new int Foo() => base.Foo();
}

class AnotherDerived : Base<string>
{
    public new string Foo() => base.Foo();
}
```

Comment: But you didn't move the method, you are adding new one. Actually, you can make `Foo()` method virtual and override it only when needed

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski in my case there is nothing the override. The implementation would be identical for the two derived classes, that's why I would like to consolidate them in a shared generic method.

Comment: You don't need to redefine `Foo` method in derived classes to call base method, just call the base method, your first option looks fine. And it isn't fully clear, what is your question about, IMO

Comment: I think you should be fine from the provided examples. If you unsure of this change, you can move it with new name with `protected` modifier, then change current method to call the new one. Test it, then publish it to the users, if you see a good feedback, you can move it and make it public in the base, then make the new method `private` on the next update. Then in give it a time to see the feedback, if everything is good, you can move the new method logic to the actual one in the parent, and get rid of it from your code. so the changes are baby steps! one change at time. .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't want to introduce breaking changes to my users

That's smart.

> my question is whether this pull up in any way be considered a breaking change?

You asked if it could in **any way** be a breaking change, and the answer is yes, there are some ways it *could* be a breaking change. However, the ways that it could be a breaking change are *obscure* and *unlikely to be a factor in real-world code*.

Let's start by clarifying what we mean by a *breaking change*. For our purposes let's say that there are two software packages, Alpha 1 and Bravo 1, where Alpha is a dependency of Bravo. The question is: suppose we have Alpha 2 and we recompile Bravo without changes, but against Alpha 2.  If Bravo no longer compiles, or worse, compiles but changes its behaviour, the change to Alpha is said to be *breaking* Bravo.

The question then is, can we come up with a Bravo that consumes your two different class libraries, but does not compile in the latter version?  I'll assume that all your classes and members are `public`.  Also, we don't need the base class to be generic, so let's simplify that:

```
// Alpha 1
public class Base { }
public class Derived : Base { public int Foo() => 0; }

// Alpha 2
public class Base { public int Foo() => 0;}
public class Derived : Base { }
```

Here is a Bravo that compiles with v1 but not v2:

```
class Bravo
{
  static void M(Action<Base, Derived> a) {}
  static void M(Action<Derived, Base> a) {}
  static void Main()
  {
    M((x, y) => { x.Foo(); });
  }
}
```

What happens in v1?  We have two choices: either `x` is `Base` or `x` is `Derived`.  The former is impossible because `Base` has no `Foo`.  Therefore `x` is unambiguously `Derived` and the program compiles.

But with v2, we have two choices: either `x` is `Base` or `x` is `Derived` and both have `Foo`, so we cannot unambiguously say which `M` is meant.  Therefore we fall back to a tiebreaker round, but we have no reason to prefer `Action<Base, Derived>` to `Action<Derived, Base>` or vice versa. Bravo fails to compile with an ambiguity error.

---

**EXERCISE**: Construct a class Bravo that compiles with both Alpha 1 and Alpha 2, but where overload resolution chooses a *different* method for each. That's the more subtle kind of breaking change. (Though we hope that changing which method is called does not change the meaning of the program very much; it would be bizarre if there were two methods with the same name on the same class that did very different things!)

---

When we added lambdas to C# 3 I had many long meetings in Mads' office discussing this scenario and we decided that it was worth adding these rare-in-practice breaking change scenarios to the language in exchange for the power that came with type inference on lambdas.

---

UPDATE: There are other ways in which moving a method to a base class can cause a change in behaviour that does not involve bizarre lambda binding.  For example, consider:

```
// version 1
class B 
{
  public void M(int x, int y) { Console.WriteLine(1); }
}
class D : B 
{
  public void M(int x, short y) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
}
...
new D().M(1, 1); // 2
```

This is a little surprising, but remember that what we have here is a call with **three** arguments: `this` is `new D()`, `x` and `y` are both `1`.  Our choices of overloads are a method that takes `D` for `this`, `int` for `x`, and `short` for `y`, and a method that takes `B` for `this`, `int` for `x` and `int` for `y`.

In C#, a literal `int` is automatically convertible to `short` if it is in the range of a short.  So the question then is: which is more important? That we closely match the receiver to `this`, or that we closely match the compile-time type of the literal to the type of `y`?  C# decides that the receiver is always more important than any argument, and so chooses the more-derived method.

If we then move the method into the base class:

```
// version 2
class B 
{
  public void M(int x, int y) { Console.WriteLine(1); }
  public void M(int x, short y) { Console.WriteLine(2); }
}
class D : B  { }
...
new D().M(1, 1); // 1
```

Now the compiler has no difference in the receiver type of the two methods, so that is no longer a tiebreaker. The only tiebreaker that is now available is "should we think of `1` as more like `int` or `short`?" and the answer is `int`, so this prints `1`.

---

ANOTHER UPDATE:

The original poster has clarified that the question was intended to specifically solicit opinions on the fact that the method is becoming generic in the updated version; I did not understand that the emphasis was on the genericity, and instead concentrated on the fact that the method was moving to a base class irrespective of whether it was generic or not.

There are also some potential issues with making a non-generic method into a generic one, or, as in this case, changing a method in a way that preserves its signature but adds a generic substitution step to do so. But as I noted in the earlier part of this answer, those issues should be exceedingly rare in real-world code.

C# has a last-chance tiebreaker rule that says that if during overload resolution you have two methods that are *exactly identical in their parameter types*, but that one of those methods got its signature by generic type substitution and the other did not, then the "natural" method wins.  That tiebreaking rule can in theory lead to a breaking change with the proposed refactoring, but this situation is extremely rare in realistic code. I tried, but could not easily produce a scenario in which your refactoring would run into this problem. I'll keep playing around with it though, and if I come up with anything plausible I'll add another update.

Comment: A new compiler warning, as it occurs when Bravo derives from Base and implements a method `Foo()`, is it considered a breaking change too?

Comment: @LucaCremonesi: Good question. A lot of people compile with "warnings are errors" turned on, and so there is an argument to be made that introduction of a new warning is a breaking change. But in that case you should be happy that you got the break, since the warning is probably telling you something important!

Comment: @Davi: I am not. I have been on the specification teams for JavaScript, C#, VBScript and Hack, contributed to the VB design process, and have attended a small number of Python design team meetings as an interested observer. I am also a member of the Java Experts Group but I do not usually participate in their design discussions. Why do you ask?

Comment: @EricLippert Sorry I said "after" instead of "before". I'm actually dancing like a crazy person to an LCD Soundsystem show from last year. TMI! Anyway, what I wanted to joke about is that soon C# will be so arcane you won't know what constructor you're using unless you read the documentation carefully. I don't actually think that, the language is pretty great and kind to beginners, unlike merciless C++ (it feels like you need to be initiated in a secret society to understand **the real deal C++**, the pre-processor directives all over sure don't help...) Anyway, I admire your work a lot! :D

Comment: @EricLippert While I learned something else that I intended to ask for, my question is more about the change of return type from `int` to `T`. I've updated my question to hopefully be more clear about that.

Comment: @JonasNyrup: The return type of the method in your derived class is still `int`, not `T`. However, that does bring to mind another possible extremely rare breaking change; I'll see if I can find some time today to explain it.

Comment: @JonasNyrup: I added some updates with some thoughts on your clarified problem.

Answer (score 1):

If that's really all you do, then it's not a breaking change. There is no possible way that any client code relying on the old design could be broken.

The second version, I'm not so sure. You'd be hiding the base method (you should use the `new` keyword, by the way, to make your hiding intentions clearer), and that changes the way the method resolution happens at runtime. It could be fine (albeit really ugly) or it could mess something up.

**EDIT**: Actually, I just thought of a way client code could be broken, but that shouldn't be considered a breaking change, more like a curiosity, unless using reflection on your dll is something to be expected: any code using `System.Reflection.TypeInfo DeclaredMethods` property or `GetDeclaredMethods()` method would be potentially broken.

In any case, client code that uses reflection **is supposed** to be recompiled and potentially fixed when referenced libraries are updated.

Comment: Are you *sure* that there is *no possible way* to introduce such a break?  How much money would you care to bet on that claim? :)

Comment: Quoting Eric: [Every public change is a breaking change](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/01/09/every-public-change-is-a-breaking-change/).  And no, this doesn't rely on reflection.  Mind you, I'm not sure that's really saying much that his answer doesn't cover.

Comment: As Eric, Mads and the rest of the team make C# fancier it also gets closer and closer to C++'s potential for esotericism (although still beautiful, and I don't mean it metaphorically: I think C# code is very pleasing aesthetically. It's satisfying to look at your work after you write it, not only because it works, but also because it looks so damn good!)